# Rotate a table from R markdown in pdf

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm writing in R Markdown and have a contingency table that is quite wide. I am converting the R markdown document to a PDF using pandoc.

Is it possible to rotate or shrink the table? Ideally this would be done without having to switch to LaTeX formatting.

**My Attempts:**

I've been abusing the figure options in knitr to attempt this, but whether I use kable or xtable, I haven't had any luck. Some permutations I have tried include:

````
```{r out.extra='angle=90', results='asis'}
library(knitr)
kable(iris[1:5,])
``` 

``{r size='footnotesize', results='asis'}
library(knitr)
kable(iris[1:5,])
```

```{r out.extra='angle=90', results='asis'}
library(xtable)
xtable(iris[1:5,])
```

```{r size='footnotesize', results='asis'}
library(xtable)
xtable(iris[1:5,])
```
````

All of these show the table nicely, but do not rotate it.

The code I'm using to knit is:

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('table.Rmd', 'table.md')"
```

And to convert to pdf:

```
pandoc table.md -o table.pdf
```

Comment: An alternative "solution" would be using [pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#tables) that can split "too wide" tables into multiple pieces.

Comment: My actual table is a contingency table, so it's important to be able to read all the way across it for comparison.

Comment: You could try plotting the table as an image [something like this](http://blog.mollietaylor.com/2013/10/table-as-image-in-r.html), which could presumably be more easily manipulated.

Comment: Thanks Gregor! This was the approach that worked for me!

Comment: This works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849814/rstudio-rmarkdown-both-portrait-and-landscape-layout-in-a-single-pdf

Answer (score 16):

The `out.extra='angle=90'` only works on Figures, and unfortunately not tables. Here are several potential approaches:

**KableExtra (Rotate Page)**

You can easily rotate tables using the useful addon package `kableExtra`. Specifically, the `landscape()` function will put the table on an single landscape page. It’s useful for wide tables that can’t
be printed on a portrait page.

```
library(kableExtra)

kable(iris[1:5,],
      format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kableExtra::landscape()
```

The limitation of these function is that it does force a new page, so depending on the size of your table it could leave a bit of blank space.

**KableExtra (Scale Width)**

You can scale the width of the table using the function `kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down")`. This will force the table to the width of the page.

```
   kable(iris[1:5,],
          format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE) %>%
          kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down")
```

> For more examples of the kableExtra package, check out the package here: https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

**Stargazer (Rotate Table)**

Other options are available, but these largely require the installation of additional LaTeX packages. For example, the `stargazer` package can print tables in landscape using the `float.env` argument:

````
```{r, results="asis"}
stargazer(iris[1:5,], 
          float.env = "sidewaystable")
```
````

This requires `\usepackage{dcolumn}` in LaTeX preamble

> Read more about customising your LaTex preamble here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown

Comment: `kableExtra` just gives me `## Currently generic markdown table using pandoc is not supported.`

Comment: You probably haven't said `format = "latex"` within the kable function.

Comment: Yes, that was it.

Comment: I came across this solution first when looking for how to implement sidewaystables with knitr and stargazer but couldn't get it to work using `\usepackage{dcolumn}`. Instead, I found in this response that I had to use `\usepackage{rotating}`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34292292/5577741

Answer (score 2):

You can add some LATEX code in your Rmd file :

````
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

Some text on a portrait page.

\newpage
\blandscape

## Title, lorem ipsum

```{r, results = "asis"}
kable(iris[1:5,], caption = "Lorem again")
```
Lorem ipsum...

\elandscape

Some other text on a portrait page.
````

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use t()?

```
library(xtable)
xtable(t(iris[1:5,]))
```

If your table is still to long, split it up into multiple tables. e.g.:

```
splits = floor(seq(1, ncol(iris), length=5))
for(i in 2:length(splits)){
 mini.tab = iris[ , splits[i-1]:splits[i]]
 xtable(mini.tab)
}
```

Comment: While that works fine for this example, my actual table is still too wide transposed!

Comment: Yes, splitting the table would normally be a good option, but my table is a contingency table, so splitting it makes it much less comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Two other solutions that work if you want the titles on the same page as the table, using kable and kableExtra:

1. Posted by user16024709 in this question [Rotate table pdf output from Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693683/rotate-table-pdf-output-from-markdown/69735492#69735492) (including a for-loop):

---

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  \usepackage{lscape}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```  

Report page - 


```{r results='asis', warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}  
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
for (i in 1:3) {
  cat('\\rotatebox{90}{')
  print(kable(iris[i:(i+5), ], format = "latex", align = "c", booktabs = TRUE,
          row.names = FALSE))
  cat('}')
  cat("\n\\newpage\n")
}
```
````

2. Based on the first solution, but adjusted by me in order to use kable_styling. You have to add 'position="left"'. Otherwise you get an "! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode." Also no for-loop included in this.

---

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  \usepackage{lscape}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```  
    
```{r warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}  
library(kableExtra)
table <- kable(iris[1:5, ], format = "latex", align = "c", booktabs = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
table <- kable_styling(table, latex_options = c("striped"), position="left", font_size=7, stripe_color="#D3D3D3")
```

# Some Title

```{r results='asis', warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}  
library(knitr)

cat('\\rotatebox{90}{')
print(table)
cat('}')
cat("\n\\newpage\n")
```
````