# R Markdown Smaller Output Matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix that is being outputted in to a RMarkDown PDF.

It is several columns wide and 10 rows. Is there a way to force it fit horizontally as oppose to going further down the page?

`{r out.width = '200px', out.height = '200px'}
   mat`

Right now it looks like this....

[image]

Comment: Would you consider making the pdf landscape instead of portrait? That would be a very easy solution. 

Otherwise, and people can feel free to correct me, you'd have to convert the output into a table/data.frame and then put that into the pdf. Which isn't horrible, just not as easy as making the page landscape.

Comment: I don't mind. As long as it fits nicely...

Comment: Well here is an entry for making a landscape page:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849814/rstudio-rmarkdown-both-portrait-and-landscape-layout-in-a-single-pdf

see if you like it, if not we can continue...

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine override the default wrapping width.

````
```{r}
options(width=100)
mat
'''
````

Note sure that this will be optimal/good choice when you convert your markdown to pdf...