# Knitr: Figure caption after \newpage is ignored

Tags: r, pdf-generation, knitr

I'm using `\newpage` to force my figures to be in the right spot.
I have added `\newpage` after the figure chunk. However, the figure caption is ignored when rendering the PDF.

I have tried `fig.pos` to force my figures, but it didn't work. I've also tried `\clearpage` and `\pagebreak`. None of them seem to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or what I need to add to make it work?

Here's an example:

````
```{r eg, fig.width=4, fig.height=6, echo=FALSE, fig.pos="!H", fig.cap="\\label{fig:eg}Plot example", dev='png'}

 plot(c(1:20))

```

\newpage

some text some text 

some other figure (with proper caption)

some text
````

In the PDF version after using the figure label, I only see Figure?? as the caption.

Comment: I can't confirm the error; with your example I do obtain the caption in the PDF output. Please post a minimal working example which produces the undesired results.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I cannot confirm it either with this example.  I don't know what's wrong with my report. All figures have caption, except the two chucks that I'm using the \clearpage (or \newpage). My report is a bit complicated and it used multiple packages, that's why I couldn't put it here. I understand that I have to provide an example, but I was wondering if anybody has a similar problem.
Could you please tell me how I can handle figure position, to force the figure be shown on the spot I want?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about precise instructions on how to handle the position of images. Just one comment concerning the missing caption: you might want to make sure that there's an empty line between the end of the chunk ```` and the \newpage command (like in in your example above). Else I think that the caption won't be displayed - I don't know why. Wishing you good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and here is a reproducible result.

For me, the problem comes about when I use the [lscape package to have one page landscape.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849814/rstudio-rmarkdown-both-portrait-and-landscape-layout-in-a-single-pdf) using header.tex:

```
\usepackage{lscape}
\newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
\newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}
```

Here is a code that produces undesired results.

````
---
title: "Figure missing for new landscape page"
author: "Tamara vdDoes"
date: "August 31, 2016"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes  
    includes: 
      in_header: header.tex
---

# Figure title that works
```{r eg, fig.width=4, fig.height=6, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Figure that works"}
plot(c(1:20))
```

\newpage
\blandscape

# Figure title that does not work
```{r eg2, fig.width=4, fig.height=6, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Figure that does not work"}
plot(c(1:20))
```
\elandscape
````

`