# R Markdown - positioning plots on page horizontally

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have question about positioning plots on page in R Markdown. This is little example:

````
---
title: "Example"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
set.seed(1213)
x = cumsum(rnorm(1000))
plot(x, type = 'l')
```
````

I would like to have this plot on entire page rotated horizontally 90°. It is even possible ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps `{r, fig.width = 10}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the output to be in horizontal mode, use

```
---
title: "Example"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
---
```

If you want a mix of landscape and portrait, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27334272/2103175

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your hep.

Comment: I also found this: `\newpage
```{r, out.extra='angle=270', results='asis'}
set.seed(1213)
x = cumsum(rnorm(1000))
plot(x, type = 'l')`
```