# Where to put header.tex to change page to Landscape Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, landscape, pandoc, shiny

I read here how to add what is needed to give me the ability to change my page to landscape:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849814/rstudio-rmarkdown-both-portrait-and-landscape-layout-in-a-single-pdf)

However I have saved the header.tex file everyplace I could think of and I still end up getting the following error:

```
Called from: (function (e) 
{
if (inherits(e, "shiny.silent.error")) 
    return()
handle <- getOption("shiny.error")
if (is.function(handle)) 
    handle()
})(list(message = "pandoc document conversion failed with error 43", 
call = NULL))
Browse[1]>
```

I know this is do to me typing \blandscape and \elandscape because the PDF works as soon as I delete those commands. What I need help with is figuring out where to save the header.tex file to so that Rmarkdown knows how to locate it. Thanks in advance for everyone's your help!

Follow up:
Taking scoa's advice about adding it to my header I edited the top of my Rmd file to the following. Unfortunately it still didn't work.

````
---
title: "Lake Report"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
---
\newpage
\blandscape
```{r Non-Seasonal MK results, echo=FALSE}
# MKanalysis <- reactive(HM_MK(data = NonSeasonalData(),n = 4))
kable(MKanalysis(), caption = "Non-Seasonal Trend Analysis")
```
The results of the Mann Kendall analysis....
\elandscape
````

Latex program/verision: pdfTex, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17

Comment: to debug the issue, it usually helps to convert to latex first (`pandoc input.md -o file.tex`) and running that with `pdflatex file.tex` to see what exactly the issue is...

Comment: The issue is that Rmarkdown is unable to recognize the commands \blandscape and \elandscape. When those two commands are removed the PDF exports. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the `header.tex` in the same directory your Rmd file is. Also, rather than an external file, you could just add those commands in your yaml front matter, a more portable solution:

```
---
title: "Lake Report"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
---
```

Comment: ---
title: "Lake Report"
output: 
pdf_document:
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
---

Comment: I tried your new edits and I still get the same error. At the top is what I changed it to

Comment: Do I need to add usepackage{lscape} to my code or install something? Sorry if this is painstakingly easy, I am fairly new to Rmarkdown!

Comment: your example works fine on my machine. It may depend on your latex installation

Comment: I currently have pdfTex, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 <Tex Live 2016> is there a better LaTex program you would recommend that would be better?