# R: how to print plots with both portrait and landscape orientation in the same pdf

Tags: r

I have [seen this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849814/rstudio-rmarkdown-both-portrait-and-landscape-layout-in-a-single-pdf). However, I am not using Rmarkdown. I just have a list of plots to print to the pdf. And I want some of them to be printed landscape and some of them to be printed in a portrait manner and at the same time, all these plots will be within the same pdf.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: afaik the whole point of Rmarkdown is that it lets you use `knitr` to create pdfs. Why not just put your code into an .Rmd?