# How can I change paper size when using Knit PDF in RStudio throughout a document?

Tags: pdf, latex, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I am looking for ways to change the paper size throughout a pdf document. I know that I can specify `classotion: a3paper` for the entire document in the yaml header. I also know that I can change margins with the `geometry package` (`\newgeometry{· · ·}` and `\restoregeometry`) throughout a document. Unfortunately, there is no option to change paper sizes, with the geomerty package, throughout a document though.

I would like to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849814/rstudio-rmarkdown-both-portrait-and-landscape-layout-in-a-single-pdf) but with paper size instead.
Is it even possible?

I am asking because I have some wide tables in my document where letters and numbers overlap when having a(4|5|6)paper specified. Other tables are narrow and I would like to have them bigger.

My table output is not from `kable` or any other easily modifiable package outputs e.g `xtable`. So what I am saying is I can't modify the dimensions of my table in my code.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `geometry` package knows about `a3paper`, so the following works for me

```
---
output: pdf_document
geometry: a3paper
---

test
```

producing a PDF with page size "841.89 x 1190.55 pts" (A4 would be "595.276 x 841.89 pts"). For readability you should use at least two columns for the text, though.