# How to print PDF tables created with kable in landscape layout with a caption?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

Context: I am knitting an `Rmarkdown` report mixing landscape and portrait layouts. I use the technique described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41945462/10264278.

Problem: there is an unexpected table layout problem. when the table is made using `kableExtra::kable()` it does not follow the expected orientationif a caption is filled in `kable(caption =...)`.

Reproducible example:

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=FALSE, message=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
```

\blandscape
```{r}
mtcars # displays properly

mtcars %>% kable(caption = "test", digits = 2) # the table follows the landscape layout and does not remains "still"/"horizontal"
```
\elandscape
````

The output:

Table on the left (`mtcars`) is displayed as expected. But, if I use `kable()` the table *"turns with the page"* witch is not expected.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I am aware that `kableExtra::landscape()` exists. But this function creates a new page for each table. Here I have many few-rows tables that are very wide. Thus I do not want to have a single table per page.

Example:

````
```{r}
head(mtcars, 5) %>% kable(caption = "test", digits = 2) %>% landscape(margin = NULL)
head(mtcars, 5) %>% kable(caption = "test", digits = 2) %>% landscape(margin = NULL)

```
````

Output:
[image: enter code here]

**EDIT 2:**

This problem occurs only if a caption is specified in `kable(caption = ...)`.

Example:

````
\blandscape
```{r}
mtcars # displays properly

mtcars %>% kable(digits = 2) # the table follows the landscape layout and does not remains "still"/"horizontal"
```
\elandscape
````

Output:
[image]

Comment: did you find a way to do this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Severe_Dragomere unfortunately no, I had to gave up. I went back to use MS Word with package [flextable](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/index.html#flextable-r-package) that has amazing export capabilities and custom options.