# how to save table created by tableby function in landscape r

Tags: r, pdf, save, latex, landscape

I am using the function `tableby` from the `arsenal` package in R. To produce beautiful tables I am using this function in RMarkdown. Then, a pdf file is created via latex. Specifically, the code I am using in RMarkdown is

````
```{r}
controls = tableby.control(test = FALSE,
                           total = TRUE,
                           totel.pos = 'before',
                           digits = 0,
                           digits.count = 0,
                           digits.pct = 1,
                           digits.n = 0,
                           numeric.stats = c('min', 'mean', 'median', 'q1q3', 'max', 'sum'), 
                           stats.labels = list(N = 'Count', min = 'Min.', mean = 'Mean', 
                                               median = 'Median', q1q3='Q1,Q3', max = 'Max.', sum = 'Sum'),
                           selectall.stats = c('N', 'Nmiss', 'countrowpct'))
```

```{r, results='asis'}
t1 = arsenal::tableby(cluster ~ ABCD.InvSales + X2020, data = data_complete_test, control = controls)
summary(t1, test = FALSE)
```
````

and some reproducible data can be found here

```
data_complete = structure(list(ABCD.InvSales = structure(c(3L, NA, NA, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, 
NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, NA, 
2L, 1L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 1L, 3L, NA, 3L, 1L, 2L, NA, 3L, 
NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, NA, 
NA, 1L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), X2020 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1904.52, 
NA, 136.04, 6457.26, NA, 595.08, 743.5, 643.35, NA, 64946.03, 
NA, 38.8, NA, 4118.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2674.488028, 
NA, 628.62, NA, 248.7697993, NA, NA, NA, 66165.44, 1749.68, NA, 
NA, 5110.64, 18319, NA, NA, NA, 1167.36, NA, 391.302, 16633.18, 
NA, NA, 1126.06, 6528.09, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 310.06, 242.24, 
NA, NA, 57.42, 122.36, NA, 486.1830396, 636, NA, 545.1747764, 
111.75, 2984.59, NA, NA, 8144.78, 31.6, NA, 52.8, 193.31, NA, 
NA, 6786.800793, NA, 4792.34, 82.12, NA, NA, NA, 2068, 114.93, 
NA, NA, NA, 192.598074, 114.34714, NA, 2846.15, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), cluster = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 100L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I am satisfied with the table which is produced in a pdf file. But, my question is how to be able to save the resulting pdf table in landscape format in order to fit more columns on one page?

If anything is unclear, please let me know and I will do my best to explain!

Comment: RMarkdown uses LaTeX to produce PDF files, and that's where I'd look for the solution.  This question gives several suggested LaTeX packages:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode .  They aren't standard packages, so you'll need to use `extra_dependencies` in your YAML header to include them.  Then just put the LaTeX wrapper (e.g. `\begin{landscape} ... \end{landscape}`) around your chunk to produce the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some research I found the following two solutions which both worked fine for me. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849814/rstudio-rmarkdown-both-portrait-and-landscape-layout-in-a-single-pdf) question helped me a lot and I just combine two answers now.

When you want to knit the PDF file to landscape mode, the only thing you need to add is classoption: landscape. That is,

```
title: "Landscape and Portrait"
author: "Jung-Han Wang"
date: "Thursday, March 19, 2015"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
```

Then, if you want some pages in portrait and in landscape mode a possibility to avoid the necessity to create a separate `header.tex` file is to define it in the YAML header the following way

````
---
title: "Mixing portrait and landscape WITHOUT a header.tex file"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
output: pdf_document
---

Portrait
```{r}
summary(cars)
```

\newpage
\blandscape
Landscape
```{r}
summary(cars)
```
\elandscape

\newpage
More portrait
```{r}
summary(cars)
```
````