# Create a multiple page orientation in a single quarto PDF output

Tags: pdf, latex, landscape, quarto

The idea is to replicate the PDF output on `rmarkdown` in `quarto`, in this case, is creating a multiple-page orientation on a single document. In `rmarkdown` I can do it easily by using this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849814/rstudio-rmarkdown-both-portrait-and-landscape-layout-in-a-single-pdf). However, I could not do that in quarto, it keeps sending the error message

```
compilation failed- error 
Undefined control sequence.
l.201 \blandscape
```

Here is my code:

```
---
title: "Portrait and Landscape"
format:
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
      - packages.tex
---

# Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

\newpage
\blandscape

# Running Code

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

You can add options to executable code like this 

The `echo: false` option disables the printing of code (only output is displayed).

\elandscape
```

Interestingly, I can create a multiple page orientation by modified the YAML and inserting raw latex to start and end the landscape page, but it will erase all the `rmarkdown` formatting and turned it into normal text inside the landscape page:

```
---
title: "Portrait and Landscape"
format: 
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
        text: |
           \usepackage{pdflscape}
---


\begin{landscape}

bla bla bla

\end{landscape}
```

Is there any workaround on this matter?

PS: my header.tex contains this stuff

```
\usepackage{pdflscape}
    \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
    \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
```

Comment: Whats the content of your `packages.tex`?

Comment: I have updated the `packaged.tex` contents in my question, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: `lscape` or `pdflscape` which one do you need to use?

Comment: I prefer `pdflscape`, but anything that work is OK. I've tried both in `quarto` but had no luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Option 01

You can use `lscape` *LaTeX* package. This rotates the page contents but not the page number.

```
---
title: "Portrait and Landscape"
format:
  pdf:
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \usepackage{lscape}
        \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
        \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
---

# Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

\newpage

\blandscape

# Running Code

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

You can add options to executable code like this 

The `echo: false` option disables the printing of code (only output is displayed).

\elandscape
```

### Option 02

You can also use [`typearea` package of KOMA-Script](https://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf) to do this. To my understanding, It not just changes the page contents orientation, but also sets the pdf page rotation attribute in such a way that pages with this attribute will be displayed in landscape orientation when viewing with PDF viewers. And also preserves the page number position.

```
---
title: "Portrait and Landscape"
format:
  pdf:
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \usepackage{typearea}
---

# Quarto


Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

\newpage

<!-- changing the orientation to landscape --------------------------------- -->

\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,pagesize}
\recalctypearea

# Running Code (Landscape)

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

You can add options to executable code like this 

The `echo: false` option disables the printing of code (only output is displayed).

\newpage

<!-- % changing the orientation to portrait again -------------------------- -->

\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,pagesize}
\recalctypearea

# Quarto (Portrait)

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.
```

Comment: Well... it also worked for me, but came out with a warning 
`Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3, column 20`
Is it okay? I will consider it as an answer for now... Thanks!

Comment: Well I am completely lost with this error message? Did you run this answer as a separate quarto document and got this error?

Comment: No... I copied your code and run it as it is. It managed to create the PDF but there was some error warning followed.

Comment: I would suggest to look carefully at the yaml header or write that yaml header instead of copy paste. What about the second option?!

Comment: The second option works like a charm!!!

Comment: The second option works exactly like I want it to be, except my `geometry`-settings aren't respected on the landscape pages. Any ideas how 1) use the geometry settings from my header or 2) set the geometry for the landscape pages?

Comment: I've posted a separate question including a repex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75448582/use-geometry-on-landscape-pages-when-creating-multiple-page-orientation-in-a-s

Comment: @shafee when I try option 2 I get the error message `render fail due to invalid YAML`. I'm typing this (see below) in my YAML. What am I missing? `format: 
  pdf: default
  include-in-header: 
      text: 
        \usepackage{typearea}`

Comment: @ianaj, remove that `default` after the option `pdf`.