# quarto gt table landscape orientation for pdf

Tags: r, quarto

I have a table created in quarto pdf document using gt.

The pdf document that appears is not great because the table is too long, and it goes beyond the margins. Is there any way to change the table in a landscape position to avoid this problem?

I have tried following example,

```
library(gt)

iris_gt <- iris %>% 
  gt(
    groupname_col = "Species") %>% 
  cols_align(align = "center") %>% 
   tab_spanner(
    label = "Sepal",
    columns = c(1:2)) %>%
    tab_spanner(
    label = "Petal",
    columns = c(3:4)) %>%
  cols_label(
    Sepal.Length = "Length",
    Sepal.Width = "Width",
    Petal.Length = "Length",
    Petal.Width = "Width"
  ) 

iris_gt %>% 
  gt::tab_options(
     page.orientation = "landscape"
  )
```

Comment: I've used the method described https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337/how-to-change-certain-pages-into-landscape-portrait-mode to put a table on a landscape page

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it did not solve my case. I have added the `\usepackage{lscape}` in the preamble.tex and \begin{landscape} and \end{landscape}, before and after the code chunk. Did I approach it wrongly?

Comment: I use header-includes field in the yaml - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown

Comment: You have a "too long" table. So I don't think just changing the page orientation from portrait to landscape would make your table wide :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @shafee, but my actual table is wider and not a long table. I have used the iris dataset as an example.

Comment: Thanks @RichardTelford, but I still have issues.

Comment: Ohhh! In that case, try the second option of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74235531/10858321), which should work, since Quarto uses KOMA-Script

Comment: Thank you so much @shafee the second option worked.