# Use `geometry` on landscape pages when creating multiple page orientation in a single quarto PDF output

Tags: r, pdf, latex, quarto

I'm using the [`typearea` package of KOMA-Script](https://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf) to generate portrait and landscape pages within a single PDF document - see [Option 2 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74235531/8511459).

However, the geometry setting are only respected for portrait, but not for landscape pages.
Any ideas how:

**1. use the geometry settings from my header?**

or

**2. set the geometry for the landscape pages within the KOMA-command?**

```
---
title: "Portrait and Landscape"
format:
  pdf:
    geometry:
      - top=80mm
      - bottom=30mm
      - left=30mm
      - right=30mm
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \usepackage{typearea}
---

# Quarto


Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

\newpage

<!-- changing the orientation to landscape --------------------------------- -->

\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,pagesize}
\recalctypearea

# Running Code (Landscape)

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

You can add options to executable code like this 

The `echo: false` option disables the printing of code (only output is displayed).

\newpage

<!-- % changing the orientation to portrait again -------------------------- -->

\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,pagesize}
\recalctypearea

# Quarto (Portrait)

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`usegeometry` option can be helpful in this case. From the [manual](https://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf) chapter 20, P. 471,

> Usually `typearea` does not care much if you use it with the geometry package in any configuration. In particular, this means that geometry does not recognise any changes to the page parameters done with `typearea`, for example when it changes the paper size — a feature not provided by geometry itself.

> Once you set the option `usegeometry`, `typearea` tries to translate all of its options into options of `geometry`. If you activate new parameters inside the document, `typearea` even calls `\newgeometry`. Since `geometry` does not support changes of paper size or page orientation with `\newgeometry`, `typearea` uses internal commands and geometry lengths to provide such changes as needed.

```
---
title: "Portrait and Landscape"
format:
  pdf:
    geometry:
      - showframe
      - top=80mm
      - bottom=20mm
      - left=30mm
      - right=30mm
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \usepackage{typearea}
---

# Quarto


Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.

\newpage

<!-- changing the orientation to landscape --------------------------------- -->

\KOMAoptions{usegeometry, paper=landscape,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{right=80mm,left=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm}

# Running Code (Landscape)

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

You can add options to executable code like this 

The `echo: false` option disables the printing of code (only output is displayed).

\newpage

<!-- % changing the orientation to portrait again -------------------------- -->

\KOMAoptions{paper=portrait,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
\newgeometry{top=80mm,bottom=20mm,left=30mm,right=30mm}

# Quarto (Portrait)

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.
```

---

Also, refer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600126/geometry-of-landscape-page-by-typearea) excellent answer from TeXStackExchange which demonstrates ways to do this with and without `geometry` package.

---

*Note: I have use geometry package option `showframe` just to show the margins*

[image]