# Changing the aspect ratio for a particular slide

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, xaringan

In the R package xaringan, is it possible to have a slide with a custom aspect ratio? For instance, I would like one of my slides to have an aspect ratio of 4:3 (instead of 16:9 for the rest of the slick deck).

Comment: these posts suggest a way forward to page-wise settings (at least for print output) if you're willing to dive into LaTeX commands ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849814/rstudio-rmarkdown-both-portrait-and-landscape-layout-in-a-single-pdf

Comment: Anyone with an answer for this?