# Rotating a table in PDF output from RMarkdown with more than one page

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I want to rotate a wide table in my PDF output. I came across [this fantastic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840878/rotate-a-table-from-r-markdown-in-pdf?lq=1), but my table is longer.

When I copy/paste one of the examples shown in that question, it works nice using RMarkdown.

```
library(kableExtra)

kable(iris[1:5,],
      format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kableExtra::landscape()
```

However, if we remove the subsetting we see that the table exceeds the dimension of the page.

```
library(kableExtra)

kable(iris,
      format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kableExtra::landscape()
```

[image]

So my question is very simple: **how can we create as many PDF pages as needed by splitting the table in parts?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you try this (sorry I can't comment) :

```
dt <- iris 
kable(dt, "latex", longtable = T, caption = "title") %>% 
kable_styling(font_size = 7, latex_options = c("repeat_header"),repeat_header_text = "",
                    full_width = F) %>% kableExtra::landscape()
```

This seems to work for me.
Here's the result : [pdf output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsAU7.png)
Is it what you want?

Comment: It worked by adding at the end `%>%
  kableExtra::landscape()`. Thanks!

Comment: If you edit your comment by adding that line I will Accept your comment!