# Wide huxtable table in rmarkdown portrait pdf with page rotated to landscape

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, huxtable

Is there a way to place a wide table in an rmarkdown pdf document to take advantage of the additional width of a page in landscape orientation?

I have found the following related questions on Stackoverflow which are helpful but do not address the use of the `huxtable` package.

a) wide tables using different table packages: `xtable`, `kableExtra`, `Stargazer`:
[Rotate a table from R markdown in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840878/rotate-a-table-from-r-markdown-in-pdf?lq=1)

b) rotated long tables (`kableExtra`):
[Rotating a table in PDF output from RMarkdown with more than one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362295/rotating-a-table-in-pdf-output-from-rmarkdown-with-more-than-one-page)

c) rotating pdf page:
[Rstudio rmarkdown: both portrait and landscape layout in a single PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849814/rstudio-rmarkdown-both-portrait-and-landscape-layout-in-a-single-pdf/27344820#27344820)

### wide table in landscape pdf

The wide table works well in a pdf which is set up in landscape format.

````
---
title: "wide table in landscape pdf rmarkdown"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
geometry: margin=2cm
classoption: landscape
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(huxtable)
library(magrittr)
```

```{r wide-table, include=FALSE}
    wide_table <- data.frame(id = 1:3,
             g1 = c("some text", "some more text", "altogether more text"),
             g2  = c("a descriptive var with lots of words", "short desc", "A typical description"),
             qnt = c(2, 100, 37),
             uom = c("nr", "m", "m2"),
             v1 = c("1,256", NA, "123"),
             v2 = c("25", "6,555", "723"),
             v3 = c("12", "699", "6"),
             v4 = c("9,656",  "491", "6,235"),
             v5 = c("564", NA, "123"),
             v6 = c("278", NA, NA),
             v7 = c("10", "25,365", "1524"),
             v8 = c(22.4, 33.5, 45.8),
             v9 = c(1.25, 45.6, 0.36))

header_names <- c("ID", "Main heading", "Some descriptive text", "A Number", "Unit", paste("Variable", 1:9))

ht <- 
  huxtable(wide_table) %>%
  set_width(1) %>% 
  set_col_width(c(1/17, 2/17, 3/17, rep(1/17, 11))) %>% 
  set_contents(row = 1, col = 1:14, value = header_names) %>% 
  set_font_size(everywhere, everywhere, 8) %>% 
  theme_article()
```


```{r ht-wide-df, results='asis'}
    ht %>% 
      set_caption("Wide table in landscape document")
```
````

Results in this which is fine:
This is how I would like the table to look like in the portrait pdf with a landscape page.

[image]

### wide table in portrait pdf

#### On a portrait page

The wide table fits into portrait orientation but headers overlap and the table begins to be difficult to read.

#### On a landscape page

The wide table's dimensions are the same as for the portrait orientation with the same problems:

- headers overlap and
- the table begins to be difficult to read.

The table does not stretch to fit the landscape page.

My question: is there a way to manipulate the table to fit the full space in the landscape oriented page as for the example where the document is set up in landscape in its entirety.

````
---
title: "wide huxtable in portrait with landscape page"
output: pdf_document
geometry: margin=2cm

header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
---

```{r wide-tbl-port, results='asis'}
    ht %>% 
      set_caption("Wide table in portrait document")
```
````

\newpage

\blandscape

````
```{r wide-tbl-port-ldscp-page, results='asis'}

ht %>% 
  set_caption("Wide table in portrait document on landscape oriented page")

```
````

\elandscape

Which result in the following tables:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does `set_width` not work if you set a specific dimension e.g. `set_width("6in")`?