# how to Rotate a table in PDF output from RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

i'm using kableextra package to work on presentation tables. i want to rotate table but page number is rotated but not table.

```
mycode:
------
kbl(df,"latex",longtable = T, booktabs = T) %>%
kable_styling("striped","scale_down", full_width = F)%>%kableExtra::landscape()

and i have tried this code in stack it didn't work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362295/rotating-a-table-in-pdf-output-from-rmarkdown-with-more-than-one-page
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a long table? Did you try to remove `%>%kableExtra::landscape()`?

Comment: actually it is long table and the number of columns are also more indeed. so i want to rotate the table. after using ```kableExtra::landscape()``` the page numbers rotated but table is not getting rotated